# Revoking Permissions in app specific parmission through settings clearing the app cache

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions

I have opened the app, I am trying to revoke the app specific permissions through settings menu and now my variable values resets to null(Which means clearing the variable cache)

Is this the regular behavior when we trying to revoke the permission manually?

Could anyone give us a description about this.

Thanks.

Comment: You dont revoke permissions by clearing the cache, you find the app in your app list in device settings the click permissions and revoke/grant them in there

Comment: Could you clarify how you are revoking the app permissions? Are you clearing the cache?   

I know that apps will loose some state information when a permission is revoked. I seem to remember my apps acting like they went through a kill-restart. What variable is reset to null? Is it a user preference or just something in an activity?

Answer (score 1):

When the user revokes permissions through the Settings app, your process is terminated. Any data that you had cached in memory will be gone.

Of course, [your process can be terminated at any time, for a variety of reasons, while your app is in the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). Hence, your code should already be dealing with this case, and therefore permission revocation will not be something distinctive that you need to address.